# Coldfusion Session Timeout

Tags: session, coldfusion, cfml

I'm hoping to get some ideas on handling session timeouts in coldfusion.

Right now, when a user logs in, I set session.LoggedIn to true, then of course, when the session times out, that changes to false. All of my coldfusion pages are coded to check for this variable and if it's false, it redirects to and Access Denied page. I changed that code to redirect to index.cfm where their credentials are validated and they're redirected back to their home page. The problem with doing it this way, is if they are in one of their applications and their session expires, when they click on something, they get taken back to their home page.

I tried using a cflocation tag in the OnSessionEnd function in Application.cfc, but of course that didn't work. It's not a real critical issue but I was hoping I could get some ideas from the forum on how you handle this in your environments.

Thanks

Comment: First, this is not a forum. It is a question and answer site. Second, you should provide us with some of your code so that we can better assist you in finding an answer to your specific question.

Comment: All your ColdFusion pages are coded to check for this variable?  Sounds like a lot of repetitive code.  Are you familiar with the `onRequestStart` function in Application.cfc?  Also, when the session times out, the session scope will probably be empty, so relying on session.LoggedIn being equal to false might not work as well as you had hoped.

Comment: toleolu - The reason for mentioning the Q&A site distinction is that Stack Overflow has a different set of rules than you might expect if you are coming from a discussion forum.  While the above is certainly a valid question, "as written" it could be viewed as ["off-topic"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and potentially closed.  Typically questions should include a bit of code demonstrating the issue, like in your previous questions. Just mentioning it so it does not take you by surprise.

Answer (score 1):

The SESSION scope is renewed on every page click, or access of the SESSION scope. So, if you have a session timeout set to 10 minutes, and they refresh their page every nine minutes, their session is renewed. They will never be timed out.

The session timeout doesn't start from the time the session is created.

Comment: This is all true.  I'm not sure if it's pertinent to the question though.

Comment: Wow Evik, didn't mean to rattle your cage there by calling this a forum, sorry about that. How did you train your users so well that they close their apps when they are done? That would solve my problem since my users tend to open the app, do what they were needing to do, then start on something else. That's when the session times out. Dan, I have onRequestStart in my Application.cfc but not real familiar with what it does. All it has in there now is cfargument name = "targetPage" type="String" required="true" I'll look into what that does and post back. Thanks

Comment: You didn't rattle my cage in the slightest. There's an important difference between a forum and a question/answer site. I figured a coder would appreciate that being pointed out.

Comment: Whatever code you have in onRequestStart runs at the start of every page request.  So, if I request page abc.cfm from your site, the onRequestStart code will run prior to any code in abc.cfm.